# Linear programming precision of ratio constraint

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to solve a LP in which one of my constraints is of the form

```
A(x)/B(x) == 1
```

I transform this constraint into a linear one:

```
A(x) - B(x) == 0
```

However when CPLEX solves the problem, this constraint is of the order of ~1.e-5, but the ratio is of the order of ~1.4, which is a large deviation for my needs. Unfortunately the kappa value (condition number of the optimal basis) of the problem is kappa ~10^10, and this doesn't make things easier. I suspect this is the source of the problem.

**My question**: is it possible (given the value of kappa) to increase the precision of this constraint such as the ratio to be accurate within 2 decimal digits (at least) ~ 1.00something ?

Comment: X-post: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25389/precision-of-ratio-constraint-in-a-linear-program

Comment: You could tighten the feasibility tolerance (unfortunately for the whole model, and somewhat dangerous). Thinking aloud here: could you write this as `x1 = f(x2,..xn)` and then substitute out `x1` from the problem? I.e. handle this equation implicitly.